# OpenCL Rendering in Blender 3D

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

Hello to everybody!!!,

I have just made a PC with "AMD Radeon RX 480" Graphic Card and "AMD FX-8370E" Processor.
Operating System is Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to use Open Source drivers.
I know that recently with AMDGPU drivers this is possible.
I want to use Cycles rendering with GPU then with OpenCL in Blender 3D.
I have installed MESA 13 from Padoka repository and LLVM 4.0 + CLang 4.0.

When I execute the command:

```
$ clinfo 
    Number of platforms                               1
      Platform Name                                   Clover
      Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
      Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
      Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
      Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
      Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

      Platform Name                                   Clover
    Number of devices                                 1
      Device Name                                     AMD POLARIS10 (DRM 3.2.0 / 4.7.0-040700-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)
      Device Vendor                                   AMD
      Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
      Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
      Driver Version                                  13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
      Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1 
      Device Type                                     GPU
      Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
      Max compute units                               36
      Max clock frequency                             0MHz
      Max work item dimensions                        3
      Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
      Max work group size                             256
    incorrect number of operands in llvm.ident metadata
    !1 = !{!"clang version 4.0.0-svn289636-0~x~padoka0 (trunk)", !"clang version 4.0.0-svn286863-0~x~padoka0 (trunk)"}
    LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
```

I have previous results

GPU is seen by Blender 3D, but there is an error result in rendering try.

This is the error:

```
Device init success
Compiling OpenCL program base
OpenCL build failed with error CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE, errors in console.
Error: Failed loading render kernel, see console for errors
```

Does Someone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks!!!